Ansible playbook unable to find the module WinRM even though the package pywinrm is installed
I am facing an error while trying to run an Ansible playbook that leveraged WinRM module to interact with a Windows server.
My system specifications -

Ansible 2.17 installed in a docker based environment with base image of Alpine 3.20
Windows Server 2019 is the target VM where trying to WinRM

I have tried installing the pywinrm package inside venv as well as on base OS, but in either case I am getting the error as below -
{ 
  "_ansible_no_log": false, 
  "action": "gather_facts", 
  "failed": true, 
  "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'" 
}

Below are the packages already installed on my docker image (both in venv and base OS) -
pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
certifi            2024.7.4
cffi               1.17.0
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
cryptography       43.0.0
idna               3.7
jmespath           1.0.1
pip                24.2
pycparser          2.22
pyspnego           0.11.1
**pywinrm            0.5.0
requests           2.32.3**
requests_ntlm      1.3.0
setuptools         72.2.0
urllib3            2.2.2
wheel              0.44.0
xmltodict          0.13.0

I also tried win_ping directly on the Windows server but again the package still seems to be missing
ansible serverIP -i inventory.ini -m win_ping

Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
serverIP | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"
}

Just FYI, all of the this was working just fine with alpine 3.17.
I am not sure if I am missing something or doing something incorrect. Would really appreciate any pointer for this.
Thanks.

I was able to resolve the problem and here is the solution -
I was installing ansible from apk add command but installing ansible using pip in the virtual environment resolved the issue.
Thanks a lot for posting my question.
